# Maximal cliques bounding number of edges

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I am struggling to solve the following problem.

We have a simple (no loops or multiple edges) undirected graph with $n$ nodes. We are told that the graph does not contain any cliques with $m$ nodes ($m \leq n$). What is the most number of edges that this graph can have?

Comment: Checkout Turán's theorem.

Comment: Actually, this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973793/upper-bound-on-number-of-edges-in-graph-with-no-clique-of-size-k-as-subgraph/3974857#3974857

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!